# How To Set an local Maven Repository (Spring Cloudataflow Server) -->Pivotal CF DEV

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

Environment

- Pivotal Cloud Foundry DEV
- Spring Cloud Data Flow Server
- Spring Cloud Data Flow Shell

Maven Specific Environment Variables (Spring Cloud Data Flow Server)

MAVEN_LOCALREPOSITORY =C:/Users/xx/.m2/repository/
MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_REPO1_URL=http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot

Deploying Streams which contains  Apps locating in the Remote Repository works fine! Deploying Streams which contains Apps locating in the Local Repository crashes (org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: failed to resolve MavenResource:....).

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The property for `local` repository needs to be:

`MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY =C:/Users/xx/.m2/repository/`

`underscore` between LOCAL and REPOSITORY.

Did you see `MAVEN_LOCALREPOSITORY` anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: In the documentation I found only an example that uses the property MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_REPO1_URL the right spelling for I didn't found...

Comment: In the documentation I found only an example that uses the property MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_REPO1_URL the right spelling for the property maven.localRepository I didn't found

Comment: I try it the Same Issue failed to resolve MavenResource

Comment: Interesting. It works for me. What happens when you try using the cmdline property `--maven.localRepository=xx`. Also, I assume you are using the local data flow server.

Comment: Dataflow Server runs into Virtual Box (PivotalPCF Dev) on my local Machine

Comment: cf set-env dataflow-server MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_REPO1_URL https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot works fine

Comment: ok, if you are running the SCDF server inside the virtual box, then make sure that the maven local repository location is accessible.